# New module causing circular dependency of context in old module

Tags: magento2

Ive had a module (module2) that extends another module (module1) live on my website for 4 months without any issues. Ive just installed another module (module3) and it has caused a circular dependency in module2, which has no reference to module3 - it has really confused me. The error message is

> Circular dependency: Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context
> depends on XX\Module2\Model\Total\Quote\Friend and vice versa.

Module2s di.xl is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

<preference for="Aheadworks\Raf\Block\Advocate\Info\Rule" type="XX\Module2\Block\Advocate\Info\Rule" />
<preference for="Aheadworks\Raf\Model\Total\Quote\AbstractDiscount" type="XX\Module2\Model\Total\Quote\AbstractDiscount" />
<preference for="Aheadworks\Raf\Model\Total\Quote\Friend" type="XX\Module2\Model\Total\Quote\Friend" />
<preference for="Aheadworks\Raf\Model\Total\Quote\Advocate" type="XX\Module2\Model\Total\Quote\Advocate" />
<preference for="Aheadworks\Raf\Api\AdvocateBalanceManagementInterface" type="Aheadworks\Raf\Model\Service\AdvocateBalanceService" />

</config>
```

I'm not sure of the relevance of this but here is the Friend class in module 2 (the extension of Module 1)

```
namespace XX\Module2\Model\Total\Quote;

use Aheadworks\Raf\Api\RuleManagementInterface;
use Aheadworks\Raf\Model\Rule\Discount\Customer\Friend\Calculator as RuleFriendCalculator;
use Aheadworks\Raf\Model\Rule\Discount\ItemsApplier as RuleItemsApplier;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use XX\Module2\Model\Config;


/**
 * Class Friend
 *
 * @package Aheadworks\Raf\Model\Total\Quote
 */
class Friend extends AbstractDiscount
{
    /**
     * @param RuleManagementInterface $ruleManagement
     * @param RuleFriendCalculator $ruleCustomerCalculator
     * @param RuleItemsApplier $ruleItemsApplier
     * @param Registry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        RuleManagementInterface $ruleManagement,
        RuleFriendCalculator $ruleCustomerCalculator,
        RuleItemsApplier $ruleItemsApplier,
        Registry $registry,
        Config $config,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
    ) {
        parent::__construct($ruleManagement, $ruleCustomerCalculator, $ruleItemsApplier, $registry, $config, $context);
    }
}
```